# Write the LaTex code from a matrix in `R`

Tags: r, matrix, latex

I have the following matrix, `x`:

```
> dput(x)
structure(c(6, 4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 6, 0, 6, 0, 5, 5), dim = c(4L, 
4L))
```

i.e.

```
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    6    5    6
[2,]    4    2    3    0
[3,]    3    5    6    5
[4,]    1    3    0    5
```

This matrix can be represented in LaTex with the code

```
\begin{equation*}
  \left(
     \begin{array}{cccc}
       6 & 6 & 5 & 6 \\
       4 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
       3 & 5 & 6 & 5 \\
       1 & 3 & 0 & 5 \\
     \end{array}
   \right)\, .
\end{equation*}
```

To represent the matrix `x` in LaTex I copied every single number in the previous LaTex instruction. Instead I would like to know if there is a package or a function which, starting from an `R` matrix, allows to represent it with a LaTex code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Quinten pointed out the `xtable` package.  There's also the `kable()` function in `knitr`.  It's very convenient if you are developing your document using R Markdown or Sweave-style `knitr`.

Edit:

My original suggestion was incorrect; I didn't realize that the `pmatrix` environment in LaTeX doesn't use alignment characters.

I don't think there's any way to tell `knitr::kable()` not to include them, but I can write a little function that produce output similar to yours:

```r
pmatrix <- function(x) {
  cat(c("\\begin{equation*}\n",
    "\\left(",
    knitr::kable(x, format = "latex", 
                 tabular = "array",
                 vline = "",
                 align = "c",
                 linesep = "",
                 toprule = NULL,
                 bottomrule = NULL),
    "\n\\right)\\, .\n",
    "\\end{equation*}\n"))
}


x <- structure(c(6, 4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 6, 0, 6, 0, 5, 5), dim = c(4L, 
                                                                          4L))

pmatrix(x)
#> \begin{equation*}
#>  \left( 
#> \begin{array}{cccc}
#> 6 & 6 & 5 & 6\\
#> 4 & 2 & 3 & 0\\
#> 3 & 5 & 6 & 5\\
#> 1 & 3 & 0 & 5\\
#> \end{array} 
#> \right)\, .
#>  \end{equation*}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you do end up using R Markdown or Sweave-like input, you would put a call to this function in a chunk with "results='asis'" to embed the
LaTeX code in your document.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to write the same result without \hline and {cccc}?

Comment: Sorry about that -- I don't usually use `pmatrix`.  As far as I know the answer is "no".  I'll edit my answer to one that works....

Comment: Now edited to give you what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`xtable`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf) function with `tabular.environment="bmatrix"` print option like this:

```r
library(xtable)
x<-xtable(x)
print(x, tabular.environment="bmatrix")
#> % latex table generated in R 4.2.2 by xtable 1.8-4 package
#> % Sun Feb 12 18:29:03 2023
#> \begin{table}[ht]
#> \centering
#> \begin{bmatrix}{rrrrr}
#>   \hline
#>  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
#>   \hline
#> 1 & 6.00 & 6.00 & 5.00 & 6.00 \\ 
#>   2 & 4.00 & 2.00 & 3.00 & 0.00 \\ 
#>   3 & 3.00 & 5.00 & 6.00 & 5.00 \\ 
#>   4 & 1.00 & 3.00 & 0.00 & 5.00 \\ 
#>    \hline
#> \end{bmatrix}
#> \end{table}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>